# Code returning empty array in Javascript when filtering for odd and six digits

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I've tried several different approaches to achieving the aim of returning an array where each item is odd and six digits long, however every way I've tried seems to result in different console errors.

Errors and dataset below:

```
1 Passing
4 Failing
should return an array
    ✓  Well done!
logs
[ 123123 ]
 
should discard serial numbers with five or fewer figures
  ✕ AssertionError: expected [ [] ] to deeply equal []
logs
[ 1, 123, 12345 ]
 
should discard serial numbers with seven or more figures
  ✕ AssertionError: expected [ [] ] to deeply equal []
logs
[ 1234567, 123456789 ]
 
should discard even numbers
  ✕ AssertionError: expected [ [] ] to deeply equal []
logs
[ 1234, 123456, 12345678 ]
 
should keep all efficient numbers - those that are odd and have six digits in
  ✕ AssertionError: expected [ [] ] to deeply equal [ 234567, 456789 ]
logs
[ 123456, 234567, 345678, 456789 ]
```

Code as below:

```
function findEfficientBulbs(serialNumbers) {
    console.log(serialNumbers);
    const efficientSerialNumbers = [];
    const sixDigits = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < serialNumbers.length; i++){
        const six = serialNumbers[i]
        if (six.length === 6){
            sixDigits.push(six)
        }
    }
    let odds = sixDigits.filter(n => n%2)

    efficientSerialNumbers.push(odds)

    return efficientSerialNumbers;
}
```

Comment: Please add an example of `serialNumbers`.

Comment: Please present a proper [mre] when asking questions like this, including sample data.

Comment: Is returning a 2D array intentional ? serialNumbers is an array of string or number ? If it is a number you cannot check the length that way

Comment: Solution to what @FlorentM. mentioned could be as simple as `const six = "" + serialNumbers[i];`

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to simplify, you could update your function to only include a filter. You already have a filter, so it is just a matter of modifying it.

For this filter the number HAS to be odd and HAS to have a length of 6 to return true, otherwise it returns false and isn't add not added to the output.

I'm using String(n) so it becomes a string for using .length.

```js
function findEfficientBulbs(serialNumbers) {
    return serialNumbers.filter(n => n%2 && String(n).length == 6);
}

console.log(findEfficientBulbs([1,2,333333,555555]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findEfficientBulbs(serialNumbers) 
{
    console.log(serialNumbers);
    let efficientSerialNumbers = [];
    let serial = serialNumbers.map(function(e){return e.toString()});
    let sum = 0;
    // Write your code here
   for(let i = 0; i < serial.length; i++)
   {
       if(serial[i].length === 6)
       {
           for(let j = 0; j<serial[i].length; j++)
           {
               {
                   sum += serial[i][j];
               }
           }
       
           if(sum % 2 === 1)
           {
               efficientSerialNumbers.push(serial[i]);
           }
       }
   }
   console.log('Efficient Serial Number:')
   console.log(efficientSerialNumbers);
}
findEfficientBulbs([32438, 34193, 149143, 4329429, 98537, 238791, 23492, 298342]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function findEfficientBulbs(serialNumbers) {
    console.log(serialNumbers);
    const efficientSerialNumbers = [];
    // Write your code here
    for (let i = 0; i < serialNumbers.length; i++){
    // turn the serial numbers into a string to get the length
        let str = serialNumbers[i].toString();
    // check if odd and exactly 6 characters long
        if(serialNumbers[i] % 2 !== 0 && str.length === 6) {
                efficientSerialNumbers.push(serialNumbers[i])
        }
    }
    return efficientSerialNumbers;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how your code works and how it solves the issue?